# Designing application to support config changes without restart

Tags: c++, configuration, architecture, configuration-files, software-design

What are some ways to design an application such that the configuration can be changed without requiring an application restart?

One way is to just have a flat file with configs, and then the application reads from the configs whenever it needs a particular value and never store any config values in memory.

Another option is to allow the application to load the config file once and store values in memory, but then periodically reload the config file in case something changes.

Comment: Without more information about what the configurations are and how often they must be reviewed, you're asking how a computer program can *get data*, which is pretty broad.

Comment: a) Storing in memory is good, but if you do changes while the rest of the program is working, remember thread safety [of the map...] b) Periodial loading sounds bad, especially because you could read an incomplete file (currently written to). Require manual triggering of the reload, if the situation allows for it.

Comment: One way would be to give the application a *reload config* option so if the user changes the config file they then click the *reload config* button (or whatever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just so happens that I recently updated one of my free software packages to do exactly that. The approach I took was slightly different.

1) My application loads its configuration, parses it, and stores it in memory. I do not read the configuration settings every time the application needs the value of some configuration setting.

2) But, along with the configuration settings, I also store the timestamp of the configuration file itself.

3) When the application wakes up in response to an event, and it has something to do, it checks the configuration file's timestamp. If it has not changed, no further action is taken. The [stat(2)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/stat.2.html) system call is lightweight, cheap, and fast, and adds very little overhead.

4) If `stat(2)` tells me that the configuration file's timestamp has changed, the application reads the configuration file again.

The configuration file, as part of its format, includes an explicit "end of configuration" marker. If my application doesn't see it, it means that I should go out and play the next lottery, because I managed to hit an extremely rare race condition, in this case, when somehow my application ended up reading a new configuration file that's in the middle of being saved by the editor that I'm using to edit the configuration file at the same time!

If the code doesn't see the "end of configuration" marker, no further action is taken until the next time the application wakes up and checks the configuration file's timestamp.

5) After the new configuration file is read and parsed, I validate the new configuration settings. Some internal sanity checks occur here. If the sanity checks fail, no further action is taken after reporting the error to the system logs.

6) Only after the sanity checks pass, the previously-stored configuration settings and values get replaced by the updated values read from the new configuration file, together with the new configuration file's newer timestamp. Until next time we meet again.

P.S. The saved configuration settings are protected by a mutex. The application holds the mutex when it needs to check a value of particular configuration setting. Step 6 also acquires the mutex just long enough to replace the current configuration settings with the newly-validated updated configuration settings.

Comment: Cool approach.  Could you post a link to your changes in the free software package?  Also, could we use two versions of the config file to handle the problem of reading a file that is in the middle of being written?  Then use a symlink to point to the file that is safe to be read.  This would be similar to how version control systems have multiple branches, but a single head branch.

Comment: The two version + symlink approach was unnecessarily complicated for me, and the timestamp+EOF marker approach is much simpler. But it's entirely possible that it will work for you, provided that you update the symlink automatically via rename(). https://github.com/svarshavchik/courier/blob/master/courier-authlib/authldaplib.cpp is the configuration file implementation that I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid polling, consider using a notification from the operating system to find out when your config file has been modified. Most operating systems provide APIs that'll do this:

- Linux: [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)
- Windows: [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx)
- Mac: [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-SW4)

There are a number of cross-platform wrappers out there ([here](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) and [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/simplefilewatcher/), for example) that can simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Sam Varshavchik contains lots of good advice. However, there is other point worth stating...

The public API of your configuration class will provide one or more `lookup()`-style methods that are used to retrieve configuration values. To ensure thread safety, you *must* ensure that these `lookup()` methods return a deep copy of (rather than a pointer/reference to) the underlying configuration value. For example, if returning a string then the return type should be `std::string` rather than `const std::string &` or `const char *`.